# Calling functions in module by choice in main python program

Tags: python, function, module

Can I call function from module in the main python file by user choice?

something like this:

module file

```
def product_1(a,b):
    return a*b

def sum_1(a,b)
    return a+b
```

main file

Can I call function in the main file with list by user choice from input?

```
a=input()
b=input()
list1=['product_1','sum_1']
x=input('Enter choice')
list1[x]
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to have functions in a list/dictionary that you can call. For your case, it sounds like you need a dictionary to determine the proper function.

Your `main.py` should look like...

```
from module import product_1, sum_1
def main():
    a=input()
    b=input()
    function_mapping={'product_1':product_1, 'sum_1':sum_1 }
    x=input('Enter choice')
    print(function_mapping[x](a,b))
main()
```

Comment: tnx, but how can I call it from the main file? The way like this doesnt work: print(module.function_mapping[x](a,b)) (Error: module 'module' has no attribute 'function_mapping')

Comment: Try an `import` statement

`from module import product_1, sum_1`

Comment: Doesnt work, it gives me the same error

Comment: @LookyFunny edited my answer to match how your format should look